# Splitting a string in which delimiting string ^^^^ has special meaning for regex

Tags: java, regex

Trying to split a string like this

```
12^^^^John Doe^^^^+1897987987
delimiter is the ^^^^
```

split method does not split and instead returns entire line and single length array

```
   String[] line = str.split("^^^^");
   id = line[0];
   // code below does not work because there is only one element in array 
   name = line[1];
   number = line[2];
```

^ has a special meaning in regex so I believe this split params have to be passed in a different way to achieve the desired result, please advise.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need to escape those characters - `^` means "start of line" in a regex.

`String[] line = str.split("\\^\\^\\^\\^");`

Two `\` are needed because otherwise Java tries interpreting `\^` as a string escape character, like `\n` or `\t`.